# .Net Core deps file modification not reflected

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a .NET Core project with many libraries as dependencies.

I wanted to change code in one of the library (a dll dependency) and wanted to run the project using the said new dll.

I changed the file version of the dll in the deps.json file but when i run the project using `dotnet project.dll` I see this exception thrown:

> Application startup exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CuPletEngine, Version=16.0.229.1809, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I made the change to `deps.json` file in order to force the application to to look for a different dll version.

Why would it still look for older version?

Please help.

Comment: please post your `*.csproj` file (xml)

Comment: are you using docker?